# How to use Unicorn for Content Staging

Tags: unicorn

I've some problems in understanging how to setup unicorn for content Staging.

- First of all I've installed and setup unicorn so far for my developer Items I want to sync to my Staging server, that works fine with calling the powershell

  ```
  Sync-Unicorn -ControlPanelUrl "http://sitecore.local/unicorn.aspx" -SharedSecret 'XYZ...123'
  ```
- I've also created a unicorn config file for my content Items which my content authors will create and which should be synced between my Live and Staging environments and here I thought I could export only this yaml files on my staging system and import them on my live system and sync them there an vice versa when I want my live content on my staging machine.

Is this right or I am missing here something? And when this is right how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicorn is a unidirectional tool, designed to push developer items *up* between environments. If you're wanting to pull content *down* from higher environments, have a look at [Sitecore Sidekick](https://github.com/JeffDarchuk/SitecoreSidekick), which is designed to pull content in reverse.

In most cases, nonessential content items should not be owned by Unicorn.

Comment: I was hoping that I could access the Unicorn SPE from my local powershell console and could extract only this configuration I want to import in the other environment. Because in your blogpost you had some code examples for SPE an deserialized some psecfic configs => https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/02/Unicorn-4-Preview-Part-2-SPE-Support/

Comment: You could use SPE for such things, sure. It's a matter of how your deployment is set up - but in general, Unicorn is designed to be upwards not downwards. The main issue is that you'd have to somehow capture and source control changes made on live - which is dicey at best.